# Summation of series- substitution

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, exact-sequence

If we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nf(n)=C, C\ne0\tag 1$, C is a constant,

can we find a closed form for f(n)?.

NB :
 Given condition is that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)$ converges to a constant value $K$ and $f(n)$ tends to $0$ when n goes to infinity. $f(0)=3,f(1)=5$ Thanks

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: It is really isn't that hard or time consuming to get a pretty good idea what the answer is through a little experimentation. I would ask that the OP put forth this effort before resorting to asking us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(n)=0$ for $n>4$. Then what we have to solve is:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
(0\cdot f(0)+1\cdot f(1))+2f(2)+3f(3)+4f(4)&=&C \\
(f(0)+f(1))+f(2)+f(3)+f(4)&=&K
\end{matrix}\right.$$

These simultaneous equations have infinitely many solutions $(f(2),f(3),f(4))$.

What I want to say is, can $f(n)$ be determined uniquely?